# Convert an array to a list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list

Got a challenge to convert a two dimensional array to a html list. the array is like

```
var arr=[[1,"link1",3],[2,"link2",0],[3,"link3",2]]
```

The structure of the nested array item is `id`, `textOfLink`, `parent`. parent 0 means top level, parent 3 means the item is under another list item with id of 3.  the target output will a list in html like

```
link2
  link3
    link1
```

please note the array is not limited to 3 items, it is dynamic. any idea how to do it in jQuery?

Comment: This sounds like an algorithm and javascript question rather than a jQuery specific question. Why don't you just sort your arr by the parent?

Comment: Sorry, don't get what the 2 numbers in there are for, care to clarify? One is order the other level? And please post the example in html...

Comment: you are gonna need to give us some code...

Comment: Oh come on that takes all the Magic away :P.

Comment: Juno gives a very good answer, it solved my problem. thanks for all your help JS Stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f9wtu/1/

Here's my version:

```
var arr = [
    [1, 'link1', 3],
    [2, 'link2', 0],
    [3, 'link3', 2]
];

function processData(list) {
    var out = $('<ul>'), // or ol
        idMap = {};

    function get(id, text) {
        var $el = idMap[id] || (idMap[id] = $('<li><a></a></li>'));
        if (text) {
            $el.children('a').text(text);
        }
        return $el;
    }

    function addChild($parent, $child) {
        var $list = $parent.children('ul');
        if (!$list.length) {
            $list = $('<ul>').appendTo($parent);
        }
        $list.append($child);
    }

    var id,
    text,
    parentId,
    $el;

    for (var i = 0, l = list.length, item; i < l; i++) {
        item = list[i];
        id = item[0];
        text = item[1];
        parentId = item[2];
        $el = get(id, text);

        if (parentId) {
            addChild(get(parentId), $el);
        } else {
            out.append($el);
        }
    }

    return out;
}


$('#result').append(processData(arr));
```

Why this is a good approach:

- Everything is wrapped in a function -> reusable, clean, easy to maintain, no global variables are added exception functionName
- You are getting what you want as an output (jQuery Element) for your input (data array)
- If you look at my code, you can easily read and follow what I am each line.
- Clean code

Comment: It works like a charm. like the way you are coding. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id='container'></ul>
<script>
var arr=[[1, "link1", 3], [2, "link2", 0], [3, "link3", 2]];
var count=arr.length,
    i=0;
do{
    if(arr[i][2]==0){
        $('#container').append('<li id="'+arr[i][0]+'">'+arr[i][1]+'</li>');
        arr.splice(i,1);
        count--;
    }
    else if($('#'+arr[i][2]).length >0){
        $('#'+arr[i][2]).append('<li id="'+arr[i][0]+'">'+arr[i][1]+'</li>')
        arr.splice(i,1);
        count--;
    }
    i++;
    if(count<=i)
        i=0;
}while(count>0)
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: adding id attribute to every element is not a good idea, because you don't know if the same id is being used already or will be used by other element.

Comment: But he specify that the first element is the id

Answer (score 0):

I would preprocess your list into something more graph-like:

```
// We'll need to be able to access them by index
var byIndex = [];

// Zero is defined as the top-level object
byIndex[0] = {children: []};

// Create objects at their respectively indexed locations
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  v = arr[i];
  byIndex[v[0]] = {id: v[0], link: v[1], children: []};
}

// Fill out the tree
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  v = arr[i];
  byIndex[v[2]].children.push(byIndex[v[0]]);
}

// Add to the document
function makeItem(item) {
  if (item.children.length == 0) {
    return jQuery('<a>').attr('href', item.link);
  }

  var list = jQuery('<ul>');
  list.append(jQuery('<li>').append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', item.link)));
  for (var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
    list.append(jQuery('<li>').append(makeItem(item.children[i])));
  }
  return list;
}

jQuery(dest).append(makeItem(byIndex[0]));
```

If you have control over the data that's being used to create the list, though, you could rearrange it so that the first steps are unnecessary.

Another option is to create the items first with the ID you're looking for and then use the ID selector to move them to their parent directly.

Comment: don't use new Array().

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<ul id="the_list"></ul>

var arr=[[1,"link1",3],[2,"link2",0],[3,"link3",2],[4,"link4",0]];
var hasOrphanLinks = false;
do{
    hasOrphanLinks = false;
    $.each(arr, function(index, value){

    // make sure this element hasn't already been created
    if(!$("#item" + value[0]).length){

        if(value[2] == 0){
             // top level element
            $("#the_list").append('<li id="item' + value[0] + '">' + value[1] + '</li>');


        }else if($("#item" + value[2]).length){
             // the parent item exists, so append this item

            if(!$("#item" + value[2] + " ul").length){
                // need an empty list
                $("#item" + value[2]).append("<ul />");
            }

            $("#item" + value[2] + " ul").append('<li id="item' + value[0] + '">' + value[1] + '</li>'); 


        }else{
         // need to revisit atleast one item. The parent hasn't been created yet
            hasOrphanLinks = true;
        }
    }
});
}while(hasOrphanLinks);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EfqnT/)

Comment: adding id attribute to every element is a bad idea.

Comment: because you don't know if the same id is being used already or will be used by other element.

Comment: The questioner named the first element of the array "id", so I'm assuming it's unique. If it's not unique, then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
//For Add
var DataList = [];
var aa = $("#divArea :input").serializeArray();
DataList.push(aa);
console.log(DataList);

//for Remove
 DataList.pop();
```

Comment: Please add more details about this answer